# reload cache, reload other page web... using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, caching, video, reload

I would like to do this:

1. A web page A showing a video.ogv (using cache) in Chrome. The video.ogv is a file in a local folder
2. Then, I close and reopen Chrome, displaying a web page B with a button. In this step, I change also the content of video.ogv (but not its name) in my folder.
3. I push the button in B to open the page A using `window.open("http://pagewebA,"_parent");`

Result: Chrome uses the first content of video.ogv. I would like to display the video.ogv with the new content.

Some solutions:

a) I could disable the memory cache, but in this case I can have problems to display the video after window.open. The video on the page A is black

b) I could keep the memory cache and force to reload the cache using `window.open("http://pagewebA?x=1","_parent")`; but In this case also my video is black.

I mean, a) and b) give me a black video. I think the page A can't download the video properly because of its size, and consequently the display is black.

If I keep the cache memory and refresh the web page after using window.open, I can display the video.

Some questions for possible solutions:

1. Is it possible to use JavaScript in the page B to reload all cache before using window.open? Or maybe it's better to reload the cache related to a page (in my casem page A) before using window.open? Or maybe reload other web page in the background... But how?
2. Is it possible to preload a video or any file in the page B that I would use in the page A? How?
3. Any other possible solution?

I am using the HTML5 `<video>` tag to display the video in the page A.

One of the questions is "how do I pre-cache on Page A a video I want to use on Page B" ? The video is in a folder F. When I open Chrome with my page B, at the same time, I am copying my new video to the folder F (the name is the same but the content is different).

Comment: is your question "how do I pre-cache on Page A a video I want to use on Page B" or are you trying to do something more complex? I am confused why/how both videos have the same name but different contents

Comment: Yes, One of the questions is "how do I pre-cache on Page A a video I want to use on Page B" ? The video is in a folder F. When I open Chrome with my page B, at the same time, I am copying my new video to the folder F (the name is the same but the content is different).

Comment: if the video isn't there before you load then you'll have to load after it's moved. Is there any reason that you want to keep the name the same rather than leave the video with a unique name that you can attempt to pre-cache from PageA? The <video preload="auto"> will only preload as much as it thinks it needs so unless you get tricky (eg preloading it as blob via jQuery) the browser not you is determining what to cache